# How can I mimic the tags box behaviour from SO in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How can I mimic the tags box behaviour from SO in AngularJS?  I'm trying to do something kind of similar where the user enters a set of space/comma-delimited words and as each one is typed I want to parse it out and put it into an array.  I know there are probably 30 different ways to do this with bespoke javascript but I'm looking to leverage AngularJS in the most efficient way possible here.

At the moment I have an ng-model based on the input field and I'm doing an ng-repeat to create spans containing each tag, but angular uses commas as the delimiter and it also includes partially-formed words.  So I only want to include words that have been delimited by the space/comma and I want to put them into an array so I can perform some validation on each one as it's entered, see below.

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline" data-ng-submit="updateScore()">
  <input data-ng-list data-ng-model="labels" placeholder="Enter labels" class="form-control" type="text" >
</form>
  <span  data-ng-repeat="label in labels track by $index">
  <span class="badge">
    {{ label }}&nbsp;5&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
  </span>&nbsp;
</span>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out actually...

```
<input data-ng-list="/[,\s]/" data-ng-model="labels" placeholder="Enter labels" class="form-control" type="text" >
```